# Laravel Livewire isn't applying "checked" property in form checkbox

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to put a condition to spawn a switch toggled on under certain events, but when I livewire:model the checkbox always spawn toggled off. My blade.php:

```
<?php
                        use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
                        use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;
                        $r = $this->role;
                        $gestion = $r->hasPermissionTo('gestionar');
                        $consultas = $r->hasPermissionTo('consultar');
                        $adPe = $r->hasPermissionTo('administrarPerfiles');
                        $adUs = $r->hasPermissionTo('administrarUsuarios');
                        
                    ?>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-check form-switch col-6 pl-2">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" wire:model="role.Gestion" id="gest" 
                            @if($gestion){
                                checked
                            }
                            @endif>
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="gest">Gestión</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-switch col-6">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="cons" wire:model="role.Consulta"
                            @if($consultas){
                                checked
                            }
                            @endif>
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="cons">Consultas</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

What should I do in order to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is enough just to bind model to checkbox with `wire:model`. No need for manually setting the checked attribute.

Don't put your logic in the blade file. Set the variable in your Livewire component and bind to that variable with `wire:model`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `wire:model`, use `wire:click`

```
  public function paid() {
    $this->transaction->paid = ! $this->transaction->paid;
    $this->transaction->save();

}
```

in view:

```
<input type="checkbox" wire:click="paid()" @if($transaction->paid) checked @endif>
```